# Biased estimator for the standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Question: If a distribution is equally likely to take the values 1 or 4, show that $s_{n-1}
$ forms a biased estimator of sigma.

I started this question by finding that:
$E(X)$ = 2.5, $E(X^2)$ = 8.5, and $Var(X)$ = 2.25. But after that I don't know how to do the proof. Do I need to assume a sample size, and then show how E($s_{n-1}
$) is not equal to the standard deviation?

Comment: What is $s_{n-1}$?. What is the parameter you want to estimate?

Comment: It is the sample standard deviation. And s.d is the parameter to be estimated.

Comment: Where is $s$? $s$ is not a parameter, it is a statistic. You probably mean $\sigma$ but you are giving full information about your random variable, I don't see any parameter involved. I may be misunderstanding completely, could you clarify?